# Automatic HTML escape sequences conversion from Design View to Code View

Tags: dreamweaver

I have been searching on the web unsuccessfully for a Dreamweaver facility I know exists, and it's quite useful.

In Code View, for typing characters like "ç", we type &ccedil ; as the best practice. What I would like to know is how to be able to **type** a word that contains the **character "ç" in the Design View** and get it **automatically escaped in the Code View**, thus without requiring my own intervention to escape it.

**Is that option present among the Dreamweaver preferences?** I have not found it.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

There isn't an option in preferences to do this but Dreamweaver will do it if the Encoding is set to something other than UTF-8 or other encoding option that doesn't natively support the character.

Start a new, blank page and do Modify | Page Properties | Title/Encoding and change whatever is in the Encoding box to "Western European" and then paste the ç character.  Switch to code view and you will see the encoded version.  If your page is set to UTF-8, you'll see the ç character in both views.